# Flutter socket.io client not connecting with node.js socket.io server via https

Tags: node.js, flutter, websocket, https, socket.io

I am trying to connect flutter socket.io client to node.js socket.io client via https, but that is not happening. Via browser I am able to establish connection and also using http in mobile, but for some reason switching to https is not working.

The following is my node.js server side code.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./file.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./file.crt')
};
var serverPort = 3000;

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send("Node Server is running. Yay!!")
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('new connection');
  socket.emit('message', 'This is a message from the dark side.');
});

server.listen(serverPort, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at %s port', serverPort);
});
```

And this is flutter side of code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart';

class TestSocket extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestSocket({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestSocketState createState() => _TestSocketState();
}

class _TestSocketState extends State<TestSocket> {
  late Socket socket;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    socketServer();
  }

  // Socket Connection
  void socketServer() {
      try {
            // Configure socket transports
      socket = io('https://<localhost>:3000', <String, dynamic>{
        'transpose': ['websocket'],
        'autoConnect': false
      });

      // Connect to websocket
      socket.connect();

      // Handle socket events
      socket.on('connection', (_) => print("Connected with ${socket.id}"));

    } catch (e) {
      print('The error is ${e.toString}');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I am using socket.io version "^2.4.1" with node.js and socket_io_client: ^1.0.1 with flutter.

Comment: have you found a solution? I am having the same problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to main.dart file and please do not use the "localhost" -> 1.1.1.1:3000 is better

https://github.com/SelimhanBek/flutter-socket-io-demo this sample which is worked on https and http side, hope that useful ...

```
// Security Policy ...
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```